# using reflection to invoke methods which takes different parameters

Tags: java, reflection

I have two methods in a class ,one takes a `Comparable[]` as parameter and returns a `Boolean` value.The other method takes a `Comparable[]` and an `int` value ,returning a `Boolean`.I tried to write some methods to invoke the methods using reflection..

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MethodCalling {
    private static Class classTocall;
    private static Method methodTocall;

    public MethodCalling(String classname){
        super();
        try {
            this.classTocall = Class.forName(classname);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("failed to get class!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setMethod(String method,Class...args){
        try {
            this.methodTocall = this.classTocall.getMethod(method, args);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Object callMethod(Object...args){
        Object result = null;

        try {
            if(this.methodTocall != null){
                result = this.methodTocall.invoke(null, new Object[]{args});

            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = new String[]{"H","E","L","L","O"};
        MethodCalling mc = new MethodCalling("SizeChecker");
        mc.setMethod("isTooBig", Comparable[].class);
        Boolean result1 = (Boolean) mc.callMethod(a);
        System.out.println("too big="+result1);


        mc.setMethod("isCorrectLength",Comparable[].class,int.class);
        Boolean result2 = (Boolean) mc.callMethod(a,5);
        System.out.println("length is 5="+result2);
    }
}

class SizeChecker{  
    public static boolean isTooBig(Comparable[] a){
        return a.length > 10;
    }   
    public static boolean isCorrectLength(Comparable[] a,int x){
        return a.length == x;       
    }
}
```

The first method invocation( ie, `isTooBig()`) works when the argument (which is a `String[]`) is wrapped in an `Object[]` .. But this fails for the next method invocation which takes a `String[]` and an int..

How do I correct this?

Comment: You can overload the method.

Comment: You need to overload the `callMethod` method to work for different kinds of arguments. That's because an `int` argument would not work with `Object` type parameter.

Comment: if the SizeChecker has many other methods which take different combinations of arguments,then  will I have to write many versions of callMethod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in the line

```
result = this.methodTocall.invoke(null, new Object[]{args});
```

When you pass arguments to the method, you wrap them in another Object[], which is a) unnecessary and, when `args` contains multiple arguments (like the string and the int from your second method call), hides those arguments in the `Object` array, making them appear as *one* parameter. That is why you get the error.

Solve it by using the following changes:

```
result = this.methodTocall.invoke(null, args);
```

Then change your main method to this:

```
String[] a = new String[]{"H","E","L","L","O"};
MethodCalling mc = new MethodCalling("wat.SizeChecker");
mc.setMethod("isTooBig", Comparable[].class);
/* change here: place the single parameter into a parameter array */
Boolean result1 = (Boolean) mc.callMethod(new Object[]{a});
System.out.println("too big="+result1);

mc.setMethod("isCorrectLength",Comparable[].class, int.class);
/* since the callMethod accepts varargs, these are automatically placed in an Object[] */
Boolean result2 = (Boolean) mc.callMethod(a, 5);
System.out.println("length is 5="+result2);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. In `callMethod`, `args` is already an array. You don't need to wrap it:

   ```
   result = this.methodTocall.invoke(null, args);
   ```
2. In `main`, the warning (in Eclipse) is clear enough:

   > The argument of type `String[]` should explicitly be cast to `Object[]` for the invocation of the varargs method `callMethod(Object...)` from type `MethodCalling`. It could alternatively be cast to `Object` for a varargs invocation

   Or the warning given by `javac`

   > warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
   >
   > ```
   > Boolean result1 = (Boolean) mc.callMethod(a);
   >                                          ^
   > ```
   >
   > cast to `Object` for a varargs call
   >
   > cast to `Object[]` for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning

   Solution:

   ```
   Boolean result1 = (Boolean) mc.callMethod((Object) a);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Easy buddy, the problems(2)

1 . you pass the String array as Object array to the `callMethod()` function, while you need to pass the String array as one argument, but it will passed as 5 arguments, simple just replace this code

```
Boolean result1 = (Boolean) mc.callMethod(a);
```

to this

```
Boolean result1 = (Boolean) mc.callMethod(new Object[]{args});
```

this ensures you the whole array will passed as one argument.

2 .  and another issue, you call the method (this `this.methodTocall.invoke(null, new Object[]{args})`) with just one argument again, in fact with second call you put all the arguments as one argument with `Object[]{args}` and invoke the method.
so change this line

```
result = this.methodTocall.invoke(null, new Object[]{args});
```

with this

```
result = this.methodTocall.invoke(null, args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your String array as an object:

```java
Object a = new String[] { "H", "E", "L", "L", "O" };
```

And to use directly the `args` arguments for the `invoke` method:

```java
result = this.methodTocall.invoke(null, args);
```